# Extracting Site data through Web Crawler outputs error due to mis-match of Array Index

Tags: php, web-crawler

I been  trying to extract site table text along with its link from the given table to (which is in site1.com) to my php page using a web crawler.

But unfortunately, due to incorrect input of Array index in the php code, it came error as output.

site1.com

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="Table2">
<tbody><tr>
    <td width="1%" valign="top" class="Title2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="65%" valign="top" class="Title2">Subject</td>
    <td width="1%" valign="top" class="Title2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="14%" valign="top" align="Center" class="Title2">Last Update</td>
    <td width="1%" valign="top" class="Title2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="8%" valign="top" align="Center" class="Title2">Replies</td>
    <td width="1%" valign="top" class="Title2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="9%" valign="top" align="Center" class="Title2">Views</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="64%" height="25" class="FootNotes2"><a href="/files/forum/2017/1/837110.php" target="_top" class="Links2">Serious dedicated study partner for U World</a> - step12013</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="14%" height="25" class="FootNotes2" align="center">02/11/17 01:50</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="8%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">10</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="9%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">318</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The php. web crawler as ::

```
<?php
    function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
    }
    $returned_content = get_data('http://www.usmleforum.com/forum/index.php?forum=1');
    $first_step = explode( '<table class="Table2">' , $returned_content );
    $second_step = explode('</table>', $first_step[0]);
    $third_step = explode('<tr>', $second_step[1]);
    // print_r($third_step);
    foreach ($third_step as $key=>$element) {
    $child_first = explode( '<td class="FootNotes2"' , $element );
    $child_second = explode( '</td>' , $child_first[1] );
    $child_third = explode( '<a href=' , $child_second[0] );
    $child_fourth = explode( '</a>' , $child_third[0] );
    $final = "<a href=".$child_fourth[0]."</a></br>";
?>

<li target="_blank" class="itemtitle">
    <?php echo $final?>
</li>

<?php
    if($key==10){
       break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Now the Array Index on the above php code can be the culprit. (i guess)
If so, can some one please explain me how to make this work.

But what my final requirement from this code is::
to get the above  text in second  with a link associated to it.

Any help is Appreciated..

Comment: Can you describe what are trying to achieve ? maybe we can help you to write a better code as the PHP code above is not clean nor flexible !

Comment: i m just trying to get web crawler which can get into a link (mentioned above) and get the links along with text associated with the text into my page (page where php script exist)

Comment: I already made a code like that which does exactly the same job but for another site, since the index array arrangement is different for different sites, the index number wont work for every site. now i m stuck with getting index for this site...

Comment: I don't see any link ( no `<a>` tag) in your HTML sample !

Comment: my bad forgot to past the other row... check now...

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: @gabe3886 I m getting like `unidentified offset 1`... which i m pretty sure due to array index mismatch.. what do you think?

Comment: What happens if you `var_dump($child_first)` in the foreach loop?  That will tell you what you're getting in the `$child_first` variable, and what index options are available.  If you're only getting 1 instance of `<td class="FootNotes2"` in the `$element`, then you should use the array index 0

Comment: @gabe3886 and i did made the same code work for another site. i have posted the code for it as 2nd answer... please take a look at it.

Comment: @gabe3886 It gave an offest 1 error at `  $child_second = explode( '</td>' , $child_first[1] );`

Comment: The issue is that you're searchign specifically on `<td class="FootNotes2"` but your HTML has the following: `<td width="64%" height="25" class="FootNotes2">`.  As such, it's not actually managing to match.  The reason your other version works is that there's no height or width setting in that part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135704/discussion-between-harishk-and-gabe3886).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library, you can use the following code:

```
<?php
    require('simple_html_dom.php'); // you might need to change this, depending on where you saved the library file.

    $html = file_get_html('http://www.usmleforum.com/forum/index.php?forum=1');

    foreach($html->find('td.FootNotes2 a') as $element) { // find all <a>-elements inside a <td class="FootNotes2">-element
        $element->href = "http://www.usmleforum.com" . $element->href;  // you can also access only certain attributes of the elements (e.g. the url).
        echo $element.'</br>';  // do something with the elements.
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 10):

Instead of writing your own parser solution you could use an existing one like Symfony's DomCrawler component: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

```
$crawler = new Crawler($returned_content);
$linkTexts = $crawler->filterXPath('//a')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
    return $node->text();
});
```

Or if you want to traverse the DOM tree yourself you can use `DOMDocument`'s `loadHTML`
http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($returned_content);
foreach ($document->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    $text = $link->nodeValue;
}
```

**EDIT:**

To get the links you want, the code assumes you have a `$returned_content` variable with the HTML you want to parse.

```
// creating a new instance of DOMDocument (DOM = Document Object Model)
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
// save previous libxml error reporting and set error reporting to internal
// to be able to parse not well formed HTML doc
$previousErrorReporting = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domDocument->loadHTML($returned_content);
libxml_use_internal_errors($previousErrorReporting);
$links = [];
/** @var DOMElement $node */
// getting all <a> element from the HTML
foreach ($domDocument->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    $parentNode = $node->parentNode;
    // checking if the <a> is under a <td> that has class="FootNotes2"
    $isChildOfAFootNotesTd = $parentNode->nodeName === 'td' && $parentNode->getAttribute('class') === 'FootNotes2';
    // checking if the <a> has class="Links2"
    $isLinkOfLink2Class = $node->getAttribute('class') == 'Links2';
    // as I assumed you wanted links from the <td> this check makes sure that both of the above conditions are fulfilled
    if ($isChildOfAFootNotesTd && $isLinkOfLink2Class) {
        $links[] = [
            'href' => $node->getAttribute('href'),
            'text' => $parentNode->textContent,
        ];
    }
}

print_r($links);
```

This will create you an array similar to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [href] => /files/forum/2017/1/837242.php
        [text] => Q@Q Drill Time ① - cardio69
    ) 
    [1] => Array
    (
        [href] => /files/forum/2017/1/837356.php
        [text] => study partner in Houston - lacy
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [href] => /files/forum/2017/1/837110.php
        [text] => Serious dedicated study partner for U World - step12013
    )
    ...
```

Comment: bro, thanks for the time but. i would like to have it in my way.although its for learning purpose, i  m kinda keen into this way.. if its possible, can you please let me know how to identify array index of a html element for this web crawler. And in other case, is it the array index that messing with the code or any other , if so, please let me know. awaiting man. Thanks./.

Comment: You are trying to explode on `<td class="FootNotes2"` but in your example HTML that matches nothing. You have `width=... height=... class="FootNotes2"`. Your solution is prone to break on minimal changes to the HTML source, even the ones recommended could break, but the source needs to change in greater level compared to exploding the string. 
If you just want to parse your way maybe regular expressions could help you extract the data you want. 
But there are libraries to parse HTML/XML and XPath to filter/traverse.
Using `explode` would be useful on a more consistently formed data source.

Comment: i tried the same thing (code) with other site and it worked just fine. i feel the code is OK for what i feel like i need . help me with array index. thanks..

Comment: I think the code is not ok. This `$child_first = explode( '<td class="FootNotes2"' , $element );` will result in a one element array (zero index) it won't have `$child_first[1]` element. 
I'm adding a DOMDocument implementation to the answer, please have a look and consider it for parsing HTML this way.

Comment: i know very little about php but after looking at your code i feel i know nothing. you may have given me a right answer for my problem but since i dont  think i understand it , i can't consider it.               please check the answer i just posted..

Comment: @jkmak please take a look at the recent answer.

Comment: It's not about the indexes of your array. I cannot encourage you to go down that route, it's not a good way to parse. 
I added more comments to the code. For now you can ignore the lines with `libxml_use_internal_errors`, just focus on the variable names and the comments, it should give you enough clues what is happening. Also please read the documentation for DOMDocument http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php. Believe me, once you understand what is this DOM and how you can traverse the tree it will make you a better web developer.

Comment: where did you mentioned website link in your code to parse links..?

Comment: Dude, i know that you are trying to guide me in a safe and right way to code or most appropriate way. But right now i m begging you (figuratively) just tell me how to make the code (that i  have posted ) work.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the same code for another site. and it works.
Please take a look at it:

```php
<?php
    function get_data($url) {
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      $result=curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $result;
    }
    $returned_content = get_data('http://www.usmle-forums.com/usmle-step-1-forum/');
    $first_step = explode( '<tbody id="threadbits_forum_26">' , $returned_content );
    $second_step = explode('</tbody>', $first_step[1]);
    $third_step = explode('<tr>', $second_step[0]);
    // print_r($third_step);
    foreach ($third_step as $element) {
      $child_first = explode( '<td class="alt1"' , $element );
      $child_second = explode( '</td>' , $child_first[1] );
      $child_third = explode( '<a href=' , $child_second[0] );
      $child_fourth = explode( '</a>' , $child_third[1] );
      echo $final = "<a href=".$child_fourth[0]."</a></br>";
    }
    ?>
```

I know its too much to ask, but can you please make a code out of these two which make the crawler work.

@jkmak

Comment: This should form part of the question as a working example of something else, it's no a solution to the question you are asking here

Comment: yes, of course its not a solution.. but i just randomly posted it here... will delete it once i got the solution...

Comment: It looks like you can delete this now that you have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Chopping at html with string functions or regex is not a reliable method.  DomDocument and Xpath do a nice job.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nXB2q))

```
$dom=new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->evaluate("//td[@class = 'FootNotes2']/a") as $node) {  // target a tags that have <td class="FootNotes2"> as parent
    $result[]=['href' => $node->getAttribute('href'), 'text' => $node->nodeValue];  // extract/store the href and text values
    if (sizeof($result) == 10) { break; }  // set a limit of 10 rows of data
}
if (isset($result)) {
    echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach ($result as $data) {
        echo "\t<li class=\"itemtitle\"><a href=\"{$data['href']}\" target=\"_blank\">{$data['text']}</a></li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Sample Input:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="Table2">
<tbody><tr>
    <td width="1%" valign="top" class="Title2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="65%" valign="top" class="Title2">Subject</td>
    <td width="1%" valign="top" class="Title2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="14%" valign="top" align="Center" class="Title2">Last Update</td>
    <td width="1%" valign="top" class="Title2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="8%" valign="top" align="Center" class="Title2">Replies</td>
    <td width="1%" valign="top" class="Title2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="9%" valign="top" align="Center" class="Title2">Views</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="64%" height="25" class="FootNotes2"><a href="/files/forum/2017/1/837110.php" target="_top" class="Links2">Serious dedicated study partner for U World</a> - step12013</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="14%" height="25" class="FootNotes2" align="center">02/11/17 01:50</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="8%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">10</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="9%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">318</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="64%" height="25" class="FootNotes2"><a href="/files/forum/2017/1/837999.php" target="_top" class="Links2">some text</a> - step12013</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="14%" height="25" class="FootNotes2" align="center">02/11/17 01:50</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="8%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">10</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="9%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">318</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
HTML;
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li class="itemtitle"><a href="/files/forum/2017/1/837110.php" target="_blank">Serious dedicated study partner for U World</a></li>
    <li class="itemtitle"><a href="/files/forum/2017/1/837999.php" target="_blank">some text</a></li>
</ul>
```