# LIMITING extracted rows from Web Crawler

Tags: php, web-crawler

So, i have this awesome web crawler code. it gets requested data from the mentioned site and pastes along with link associated with it. (Good Boy)

Now the problem is, how to limit the extracted data to say 5 rows.
I tried putting "LIMIT 5" (which we usually do in php sql queries) but it didn't work..

My code goes as follows::

```
<div class="news-entry">
            <div class="newsblock">
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                    <h2>
                       <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://www.usmle-forums.com/usmle-step-3-forum/">
                            USMLE-Forums :: STEP-3         
                       </a>
                    </h2>
                <ul>
                    <?php
                        function get_datafour($url) {
                        $ch = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
                        $result=curl_exec($ch);
                        curl_close($ch);
                        return $result;
                        }
                        $returned_content = get_datafour('http://www.usmle-forums.com/usmle-step-3-forum/');
                        $first_step = explode( '<tbody id="threadbits_forum_30">' , $returned_content );
                        $second_step = explode('</tbody>', $first_step[1]);
                        $third_step = explode('<tr>', $second_step[0]);
                        // print_r($third_step);
                        foreach ($third_step as $element) {
                        $child_first = explode( '<td class="alt1"' , $element );
                        $child_second = explode( '</td>' , $child_first[1] );
                        $child_third = explode( '<a href=' , $child_second[0] );
                        $child_fourth = explode( '</a>' , $child_third[1] );
                        $final = "<a href=".$child_fourth[0]."</a></br>";
                    ?>
                    <li target="_blank" class="itemtitle">
                        <span class="item_new"></span><?php echo $final?>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>      
                </ul>        
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any Suggestions are Appreciated..

Comment: break in foreach loop after 5 iterations

Comment: and how to do that?

Comment: see the answer by Manvir singh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break Foreach loop after 5th result

```
foreach ($third_step as $key=>$element) {
    //Your Logic Here
    if($key==4){
       break;
    }
}
```

we are using $key==4 because index starts from 0 
hope you got it

Comment: dude, whats login content here?

Comment: login content . ?

Comment: @Mahavir Sing And in the other context , can you tell me how to know the array index of a html element by just looking at the script?

Comment: @harishk sorry! i mean logic i correct there

html element by index ? 
i didn't get it will you please explain ?

Comment: like can you please check my question here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137646/array-index-of-elements-from-a-site-code